# How do create a loop that triggers code when index i is X and every X + Y * i loop?

Tags: c#, math

I have a scenario where I want to trigger some code on turn 2, and after that every 5th turn (So turn 7, 12, 17, etc).

So I've been experimenting with modulus but cannot seem to get it. Can it be solved like I've attempted below or should I do something completely different?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < turns; i++)
    {
        if(i == triggerTurn || triggerTurn + 5 * i % ??? == 0)
        {
            // Code here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost got it, the issue is in the second condition in the if statement because you should take i and subtract the triggerTurn so that you have a "new" i0 which has to trigger something every 5 step:

```c
int i = 0;
 while( i < turns)
 {
        if(i == triggerTurn || (i - triggerTurn )% 5 == 0)
        {
            // Code here
        }
        i++;
 }
```

Comment: `i == triggerTurn` is not needed (`(i - triggerTurn )% 5` will be 0 anyway in this case).

Comment: Also: why modify the `for` loop the OP used into a `while` loop ?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `modulo` you don't need the two conditions.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < turns; i++)
{
    if ((i - 2) % 5 == 0)
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

But it might be simpler to just make the loop jump in steps of 5.

```cs
for (int i = 2; i < turns; i += 5)
{
    // Code here
}
```